# Matplotlib have small values and lots of legend -- Python/ Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, jupyter-lab

can you help me why there are a lot of legends and the values in the plot consists of small values? Should be zoomed in more to view the actual line plots.

Thanks so much for your help!

```
def test_stationarity(timeseries):
    
    rolmean = train_original.rolling(24).mean()
    rolstd = train_original.rolling(24).std()
    
    orig = plt.plot(timeseries, color="blue", label="Original")
    mean = plt.plot(rolmean, color="red", label = "Rolling Mean")
    std = plt.plot(rolstd , color="black", label = "Rolling Std")
    
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.title("Rolling Mean & Standard Deviation")
    plt.show(block=False)
    
    print("Results of Dickey-Fuller Test: ")
    
    dftest = adfuller(timeseries, autolag="AIC")
    dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=["Test Statistic", 
                                             "p-value","#Lags Used", 
                                             "Number of Observations Used"])
    
    for key,value in dftest[4].items():
        dfoutput["Critical Value (%s)" %key] = value
        
    print(dfoutput)
                         

from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 20,10

test_stationarity(train_original["Count"])
```

[image]

Comment: Your image is helpful, but can you also paste your code as text that can be copied here?

Comment: hi sirr added! tyyyyy